# Jasper multi column report, column span for specific fields

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I have a landscape subreport, with horizontal print order, that contains 3 columns (columns = 3 under report element).

The column simply has a textfield in it that displays a value from the query result.

The report prints 3 values per line, obviously.

The result set looks like this:

```
value | type
4     | a
7     | a
5     | b
342   | a
5     | b
```

---

What I need to do:

Depending on the type field, I need the corresponding record to be printed on the next line, as if there was a single column.  In essence, column span.

So if results are type a and type b, and b is the type that needs to be printed on its own line, a report may lay out like this:

```
a--a--a--
a--a--
b--------
a--
b--------
b--------
a--a--a--
```

Is this possible?  Any tips?  I'm using iReport.

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following:

- Add one Text Field per column (3 text fields). Each of them has the proper column width.
- Add an extra Text Field element, that occupies the 3 columns (will overlap the others in report design).
- Use printWhenExpression on all the text fields elements. The first 3 are printed if type != b. The 4th element is printed if type == b.

Comment: I think I did not state my issue clearly enough.  I'll edit the question to include more info.  Each value (a,a,a,b,a) is a record in the result set, with a type column that differentiates between a and b.